# Delay in Kafka Operations

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

During Testing I do some operation like delete a topic.
However I can see the topic after immeidately deleting it

Using: bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
It takes some time for deletion to actually occur.

This confused me.

Similarly when i produce data, i cannot consume immediately but have to wait for some time and re-run the consume command to consume data.

Is it because I am running a single node kafka set up and I am testing it too heavily.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to delete a topic, you need to enable this via broker setting `delete.topic.enable`.
2. Deleting a topic happens "asynchronously", ie, after you did issues the delete command, the topic gets marked as "to be deleted" and the broker will delete the topic at some point later on.
3. About producing/consuming: not sure. If the consumer is online and the producer writes data it should up at the consumer shortly after...

Comment: Thank You so Much Matthias.

Comment: 1.So I have delete.topic.enable enabled.                                                   

2. So I understand that topic can still be visible and will not be deleted immediately.                                                                                              

3. I am calling "bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh" immediately  after calling "bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh" and the acks is set to -1.

Comment: any way i could make the producer messages by synchronous will be useful ..preferably using "bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh"